# How can I get node value specified by another node value in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I want to get the node id value depends on another node value in C#,
example: from following xml file, I want to get node `<name>` value when node `<id> = 10`

```
<studymonth2>
  <id>11</id>
  <name>November</name>
</studymonth2>

<studymonth2>
  <id>12</id>
  <name>December</name>
</studymonth2>
```

---

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following XPath:

```
studymonth2[id='10']/name/text()
```

Simply put, this tells the parser to return the value of the `name` child of `studymonth2` with an `id` child with value 10.

**Edit**

In C#, you can either use `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` to access the node via xpath:

e.g. given the xml file:

```
<xml>
    <studymonth2>
        <id>11</id>
        <name>November</name>
    </studymonth2>

    <studymonth2>
        <id>12</id>
        <name>December</name>
    </studymonth2>
</xml>
```

With `XmlDocument`:

```
using System.Xml;
....
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"c:\temp\myxml.xml");

string name = doc.SelectSingleNode("//studymonth2[id='11']/name")
                 .InnerText;
```

With Linq 2 Xml:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
....
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\myxml.xml");
string name = doc.XPathSelectElement("//studymonth2[id='11']/name").Value;
```